# Android 4.0.4 crosswalk library webview internal video and audio not playing

Tags: android, android-webview, unsafe

When try to play video and audio source from internal storage i'm getting this error:

```
E/MediaResourceGetter: Refusing to read from unsafe file location.Unable to 
E/MediaResourceGetter: Unable to configure metadata extractor configure metadata extractor
```

And when i click play button i get this error :

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

Loaded url is :

`file:///data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/files/test/test.html`

or

`file:///data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/cache/test/test.html`

But with 4.2 and 6.0 android versions i didn't receive this error.

*I can't change files path because i must save files this path.

```
data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/files/test/....
```

Comment: check this [issue](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6081)